# xcode 3.2.1 file history via keyboard shortcut

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode

Prior to xcode 3.2.1, you could cycle through the list of files your in history through a keyboard shortcut (Cmd + Option + L/R Arrow key).

Now this set of keys will give you the history within the file (ie all of the actions you've performed in this file).

Is there a way to navigate with keyboard only between files you have open in your history list?

Comment: This is definitely a bug. Is there no workourounds?

Comment: No, it's not a bug, it's an intentional change. See jbrennan's answer and the comments on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there's something nonstandard in my Xcode config, they've just rebound this action to shift+option+command+L/R arrow. Of course you can always change the binding back to the old one if you want as well.

Answer (score 7):

Go into Xcode Preferences->Key Bindings and rebind these keys.

set Cmd-Opt-Left to View->Previous File

set Cmd-Opt-Right to View->Next File

Answer (score 1):

No. This is considered a feature of Xcode 3.2. If it bugs you (it sure bugs me!) I suggest filing a bug with Apple. The more people who dupe this, the faster it will get fixed.

Comment: How is it a bug? They just changed keybindings.

Comment: It sure bugs the hell out of me! Previous/Next file aren't quite the same, either. History gets erased after you commit saves. It's been changed, and it's annoying, and there's no way to go back. I consider that a bug.

Comment: It's debatable whether that's a bug or not. Have you filed it? https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: It used to be that if you went forward, then back, and edited the "back" file, you could still go forward. Now you can't anymore. That's a bug.